# Redis Pub/Sub listener is not a function

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have a redisClient and configured a separate publisher and subscriber with duplicate although I am not sure I need both of them. Redis server works ok and redisClient can write/read from the server correctly. This is the code:

```
  const client = redis.createClient();
  redisClient = await client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err)).connect();

  publisher = client.duplicate();
  await publisher.connect();
  subscriber = client.duplicate();
  await subscriber.connect();

  subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => console.log('received'));
  subscriber.subscribe('abc123');
  publisher.publish('abc123','lala');
```

and I get this error, the source of it starts at the line of subscriber.connect();

> Uncaught TypeError TypeError: listener is not a function
> at _PubSub_emitPubSubMessage (c:\src\server\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\pub-sub.js:304:9)
> at handleMessageReply (c:\src\server\node_modules@redis\client\dist\lib\client\pub-sub.js:233:93)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscriber listener should be provided as the second parameter to the `subscribe` function, not to the `subscriber` istance.

```
const client = redis.createClient();
redisClient = await client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err)).connect();

const publisher = client.duplicate();
await publisher.connect();
const subscriber = client.duplicate();
await subscriber.connect();

// subscriber.on('message', (channel, message) => console.log('received')); --> This line is useless
subscriber.subscribe('abc123', (channel, message) => console.log('received')); // --> Instead, you need to listen for messages here
publisher.publish('abc123','lala');
```

You can read more [here](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/master/docs/pub-sub.md#subscribing)

Comment: gave you the bounty and thanks although code doesn't work because for some weird reason they decided to make the function message,channel and not the other way. still I was stuck on something else and you solved it.